# How to add files from local to a repositiory under different account on github?

Tags: git, github

I want to push files to an admin repo on a project. I did fork and when i do push upstream master, i get fatal:unable to access 'https://github.com/original repo(repo name): The requested URL returned error: 403. Simple thing I just want to add files on my local to that repository and yet it seems so complicated. 
I have write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the origin-remote on your local repository points to the original github repository.

use *git remote -v* to list all the remotes, the *-v* flag shows the url of the remotes.

[Github help on how to change the remote](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)

Comment: Thanks. I did- push origin master- and files are now in the fork but still not in the original repo where i want to push the files.

Comment: In order to push to the original repo, the one you do not own, you need to make a pull request, and then the owner of the original repo can choose to merge your changes.

[Github help on pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/)